# custom plugin is not visible in Admin panel of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I Have created a custom plugin which is not visible in Admin panel...
directory saved the plugin in /wp-content/plugin/custom-plugin/custom-youzify-profile.php saved then in went to plugins> activated the plugin custom plugin which i have created but it is not showin gin admin panel...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Plugin
Description: Adds custom fields to Youzify user profile.
Version: 1.0
Author: Mohammed Khadeeruddin
*/

 // No direct file access
//  ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;

// Hook into the Youzify profile settings
function custom_user_details_form() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Add name field
    echo '<div class="youzify-profile-field">';
    echo '<label for="user_name">Name</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="' . esc_attr(get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_name', true)) . '" />';
    echo '</div>';

    // Add email field
    echo '<div class="youzify-profile-field">';
    echo '<label for="user_email">Email</label>';
    echo '<input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="' . esc_attr(get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_email', true)) . '" />';
    echo '</div>';

    // Add gender field
    echo '<div class="youzify-profile-field">';
    echo '<label for="user_gender">Gender</label>';
    echo '<select name="user_gender" id="user_gender">';
    echo '<option value="male" ' . (get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_gender', true) === 'male' ? 'selected' : '') . '>Male</option>';
    echo '<option value="female" ' . (get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_gender', true) === 'female' ? 'selected' : '') . '>Female</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';

    // Add bio field
    echo '<div class="youzify-profile-field">';
    echo '<label for="user_bio">Bio</label>';
    echo '<textarea name="user_bio" id="user_bio">' . esc_textarea(get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_bio', true)) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('youzify_profile_settings', 'custom_user_details_form');

// Handle form submission
function save_custom_user_details($user_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['user_name'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_name']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['user_email'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_email', sanitize_email($_POST['user_email']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['user_gender'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_gender', sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_gender']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['user_bio'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_bio', sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['user_bio']));
    }
}
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_details');
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/custom-plugin.php
```

instead of

```
/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/custom-youzify-profile.php
```